# Error while running npm command with permission error

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js, npm

I have my hosting on digitalocean droplet and my website is built in laravel
when i try to run following command then attached error occures.

command that i am running from root user.
npm run dev

[image: error showing up]

Do any body help me in this regard.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of permission issue with global installation that the `npm` `tools` denied that and I have the same issue as you have.

To solve this we have two ways:

1. Rebuild the packages:

   ```
   npm rebuild
   npm run prod
   ```
2. Or remove the `node_module` directory and then install and build it:

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules
   npm install
   npm run prod
   ```

Comment: When i run npm rebuild, it went fine. But when i ran "npm run prod" following error occured
https://ibb.co/R0J3Kwd
@Dawlatzai Ghousi

Comment: @Wajahat I have the same issue please use the second way, remove the node_modules and run npm install and build it again.

Comment: Now the command 'npm run prod' is working fine but the changes i have made in pages are not reflecting up. I cleared the cache too.

Comment: @Wajahat did you try hard refresh(ctrl+alt+r) in your browser, maybe the reason could be browser cache;

Comment: Yes it did'nt worked. Cleared Cache too.

Comment: Force node_modules cache clear by doing `sudo rm -rf node_modules/.cache`

Answer (score 0):

I just had to clear the cache of my cloudflare account for this domain and everything was then running fine. I heard this from a random post dont know but keep this noted if you guys have CLOUDFLARE on your domain :)